# Frames in Chrome Developer Tools are not auto refreshed

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

If a page with WebSocket connection is sending and receiving data from server, then Chrome Developer Tools do not refresh the Frames in WebSocket filter. However if I go to Headers tab and then come back to Frames then the data is refreshed.

Is there anyway to tell Developer Tools to auto refresh frames ?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not, and unfortunately there is no way of making it refresh.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is intentional or just a long standing bug. And if former then what drove this decision ?

Comment: No idea, neither you or I are the first ones complaining: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142280